# Android flood fill - Works on one image but does not work on a diffrent one

Tags: android, flood-fill

I am trying to make an android app that fills in the picture. Here is the code that floods the white area in:

```
public class floodfill {

    public void flood(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y){

        int color;
        int red;
        int green;
        int blue;

        color = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

        red = Color.red(color);
        green = Color.green(color);
        blue = Color.blue(color);

        if(red == 255){
            if(green == 255){
                if(blue == 255){
                    bitmap.setPixel(x,y,Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
        }else {
            return;
        }

        flood(bitmap,x+1,y);
        flood(bitmap,x-1,y);
        flood(bitmap,x,y+1);
        flood(bitmap,x,y-1);
    }
}
```

Using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RbfY.png) image, it fills in just fine.(The blue is where it filled in.)

However when I use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG80I.png) image it does not fill in everything.

How could I get this to work so it fills in everything just like in the first picture? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only fill `100%` white, `rgb(255, 255, 255)`, or `#FFFFFF`, see here:

```
if(red == 255){
    if(green == 255){
        if(blue == 255){
            bitmap.setPixel(x,y,Color.BLUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Due to the angle and anti-aliasing, maybe some compression artifacts—some image stuff—not all white-ish areas are actually white.
Open up your second image in an image editor (Paint will do) and zoom in on those not-filled areas, use the color picker to see what color it is. It's not gonna be pure white.

To make your flood fill approach work you will have to be less strict about which areas to fill, e.g.

```
if (red >= 245 || green == 245 || blue == 245) { /* ... */ }
```

Which would fill all *bright* areas.

Comment: Thanks! You helped out alot.